# Update value printed on console c++

Tags: c++, windows, c++14

How i can do to update values printed in the console in C++

Ex:_

Value Printed: 10

now as I can update the printed value?

I've done something like this:

```
void CursorXY(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coords = { x, y };
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coords);
}


int main()
{
    int x = 0;
    cout << "Value: " << x << endl;
    cout << "Some any value!" << endl;
    gotoXY(7, 0);
    cin >> x;
    gotoXY(0, 2);

    GetMessage(NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is if there are any less horrific form?
thx.

Comment: If you don't want to use OS-specific functions like `gotoXY()`, print the value without a newline after it, then print enough backspaces and overwrite it.

Comment: @Barmar - that approach used to be extremely popular back in the day.  Ah, for the VT52/VT100 era ...

Comment: I think it's still used in simple programs/scripts that don't use full-screen mode.

Comment: using ncurses library would also be a possibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably define a `field` class that stored its own position and value. When you update the value, it updates the display appropriately:

```
template <class T>
class field { 
    int x;
    int y;
    int w;
    T value;
public:
    field(int x, int y, w = 0, T value = 0) : x(x), y(y), w(w), value(value) {
        redraw();
    }

    field &operator=(T const &new_val) { 
        value = new_val;
        redraw();
    }

    voi redraw() {
        gotoXY(x,y);
        std::cout << std::string(' ', w));
        gotoXY(x, y);
        std::cout << std::setw(w) << value;
    }

    std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, field &f) { 
        is >> f.value;
        redraw();
        return is;
    }
};
```

Then we could use this something like this:

```
field<int> x(7, 0);

std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
std::cin >> x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use your `gotoxy()` function  but put it in a loop  to make it jump back
and then update.

Like in the code below..

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void gotoxy(int x, int y);
void setcolor(WORD color);
void setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(int ForeGroundColor,int BackGroundColor);
void clrscr();




int main(){
    int x = 0;

    while(true){
        gotoxy(7, 1);
        cout << "Value: " << x << "   "<< endl;
        cout << "Some any value!  " << endl;
        cin >> x; 
        gotoxy(1, 2);
    }

    return 0;
}

void setcolor(WORD color){
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);
    return;
}



void setForeGroundAndBackGroundColor(int ForeGroundColor,int BackGroundColor){
   int color=16*BackGroundColor+ForeGroundColor;
   setcolor(color);
}




void gotoxy(int x, int y){
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    return;
}




void clrscr(){
    COORD coordScreen = { 0, 0 };
    DWORD cCharsWritten;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
    DWORD dwConSize;
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    dwConSize = csbi.dwSize.X * csbi.dwSize.Y;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, TEXT(' '), dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(hConsole, &csbi);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(hConsole, csbi.wAttributes, dwConSize, coordScreen, &cCharsWritten);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hConsole, coordScreen);
    return;
}
```